# sh - appending 0's to file names according to the max

Tags: file, loops, sorting, arguments, sh

I am trying to make a file sorter. In the current directory I have files named like this :

```
info-0.jpg
info-12.jpg
info-40.jpg
info-5.jpg
info-100.jpg
```

I want it to become

```
info-000.jpg
info-012.jpg
info-040.jpg
info-005.jpg
info-100.jpg
```

That is, append 0's so that the number of digits is equal to 3, because the max number was 100 and had 3 digits.

I would like to use cut and wc by doing a loop on each of the file names, If `$1` is `"info"`, `for i in $1-*.jpg`, but how.  Thanks

I did this to start but get a syntax error

```
wcount=0

for i in $filename-*.jpg; do                                                    
       wcount=$((echo $i | wc -c))                                                 
  done
```

---

Comment: any ideas concerning this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in info*.jpg ; do
  numPart=${f%.*} ; #dbg echo numPart1=$numPart;
  numPart=${numPart#*-}; #dbg echo numPart2=$numPart;
  newFilename="${f%-*}"-$(printf '%03d' "$numPart")."${f##*.}"
  echo /bin/mv "$f" "$newFilename"
done
```

The key is using `printf` with formatting that forces the width to 3 digits wide, and includes `0` padding; the `printf "%03d" "$numPart"` portion of the script.

Also the syntax `${f%.*}` is a set of features offered by modern shells to remove parts of a variables value, where `%` means match (and destroy) the minimal match from the right side of the value, and `${numPart#*-}` means match (and destroy) the minimal match from the left side of the value. There are also `%%` (maximum match from right) and `##` (maximum match from left). Experiment with a variable on your command line get comfortable with this.

Triple check the output of this code in your environment and only when sure all `mv` commands look correct, remove the `echo` in front of `/bin/mv`.

If you get an error message like `Can't find /bin/mv`, then enter `type mv` and replace `/bin/` with whatever path is returned for `mv`.

IHTH